# How to avoid if-else statements, when choosing drives in combobox?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to get rid of if-else statements in my function, so I don't need to specify every drive possible. In this case I'm reading a .csv file. Is there any way to avoid the struggle of if-else.

Thanks in advance!

My code now:

```
if (str == "(D:)")
{
    csvPath = @"D:\file1.CSV";

    try
    {
        using (var fs = File.Open(csvPot, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var csvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
                IgnoreUnknownColumns = true,
                SeparatorChar = ',',
                UseFieldIndexForReadingData = false
            };

            var csvContext = new LINQtoCSV.CsvContext();
            var settings = csvContext.Read<Settings>(csvPot, csvFileDescription);

            foreach (var setting in settings)
            {
                tbx_ssid.Text = setting.SSID;
                tbx_pass.Text = setting.password;
            }

            if (tbx_ssid.Text == "" && tbx_pass.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data!");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File not exsists!");
    }
}
else if (str == "(E:)")
{
.
.
.
```

Comment: So you basically need to change the file path according to the drive choosen?

Comment: `csvPath = $@"${str}/file1.csv";`?

Comment: @steve like you said! and how to specify which drive is chosen...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prepare a Dictionary<string, string> where the key is the drive to use and the value is the filepath to retrieve the file.

Something like this.

```
Dictionary<string, string> fileToUse = new Dictionary<string, string>();
fileToUse.Add("(D:)", @"D:\file1.CSV");
fileToUse.Add("(E:)", @"E:\someotherfolder\file1.CSV");
```

Now it is simply a matter of

```
if (fileToUse.TryGetValue(str, out string file))
{
    // Code that uses _file_
    
}
```

Another approach is to strip from the *str* string the opening and closing parenthesys and use the string cleared for a substitution of the first two characters of the filepath

```
string noPar = str.Trim('(', ')');
string baseFile = @"\file1.CSV";
string fullFile = $"{noPar}{baseFile}";
```

With this approach however you are forced to have that file in the root folder of the drive choosen (or in some fixed location). Not always the best choice in the long term.

Comment: I know what you mean, but is it a smart way to use a Dictionary in this case and specify all possible drives (D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K...) into it?

Comment: If you want a 'smarter' way then we need a replacement approach changing just the drive letter of the path. But with a dictionary you could have different paths in different drives.

Answer (score 1):

SimonC solved my question. It works for me perfect !

```
csvPath = $@"{str}/file1.csv";
```

Comment: Don't tell me that File.Open works with a filename like _"(D:)/file1.csv"_ Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention... I've deleted the old style... I'm using now "D:/file1.csv".

Comment: OK, then you don't need the @ because there is no more the escape character in the path ("\").